# How can I switch on Flight Mode?

Tags: 10.10, networking, wireless, ubuntu-netbook

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition on a Dell Mini 9.

How can I switch on Flight Mode and verify that it's on?  Also will it survive being disconnected over a reboot?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu does not have a flight mode. I think you mean disconnecting your wireless by simply turning it off? To do that either disable the hardware switch or right click the network icon and click disable wireless.

Correct me if I'm wrong about you wanting to disable the wireless and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thats it, i didn't realise that there was a right click menu under the network icon.

Comment: Does this turn off the the Bluetooth radio as well?

Comment: no, bluetooth is managed separately, usually by gnome-bluetooth or bluedevil (kde) unless you install blueman (gnome) (in which case you would disable it from blueman).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [rfkill](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rfkill) to turn off all wireless (e.g. wifi, Bluetooth, GPS, WiMAX, etc.) radios at once:

```
sudo rfkill block all
```

To leave this "flight mode":

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Changes made via this method are not preserved after a reboot.

---

On a side note, Ubuntu [does not include a man page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wireless-tools/+bug/711011) for rfkill by default. If you'd like to be able to `man rfkill`, install the package `rfkill`.